# Windows Small Business Server 2003 -> Windows Server Essentials 2016

Tags: windows-server-2003, migration, windows-server-essentials

I have a Windows Small Business Server 2003 box that we use as a file server, domain controller, and remote access server. We have four Windows 7 Clients connecting to the SBS 2003 box. We bought a new server and would like to install and migrate the SBS 2003 to Windows Server Essentials 2016 to be able to utilize the more than 2 gigabytes of RAM and for patch support.

Concerns

*Windows 7 in WSE 2016 Environment*
After searching for quite some time I have found that Windows 7 seems to be supported as a client for Windows Server 2016 Essentials, however I have seen reports that there are connection issues. I have also researched migrating SBS 2003 to Server Essentials 2016 but cannot find a guide to explain what I need.

*Migrating from SBS 2003 to WSE 2016* .
I have tried my hardest to find a guide helping explain the process of upgrading to WSE 2016, however the only guides I can find are for WSE 2012. I am worried about active directory, folder redirection, and mapped network drives that are currently running on the old server and looking for information on how to migrate everything to the new server.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at this link. My suggestion would be to mock this up in an isolated environment if possible and walk through the entire procedure. Grab a full system backup of the 2003 server and restore it to an isolated environment and then walk through this guide. - https://www.server-essentials.com/support/articleid/127/migrate-from-sbs-2003-r2-premium-to-windows-server-2016-essentials

Comment: Thanks for the link! I'm in the process of setting up the lab environment, pain in the butt as a I am remote so attaining a copy of the server is a long process